# java server using jframe

Tags: java, jframe

i'm making GUI for my java server program but when i launch it program show white JFrame and doesn't load component into frame.
Here there's code:

```
public ServerFrame() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    initComponents();

    server = new ServerSocket(4444);
    textList.setText("Waiting for client to connect...");

    SimpleDataSource.init("database.properties");
    net = new Network();

}

public static void main(String args[]) {

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){

                ServerFrame sf;
                try{
                    sf = new ServerFrame();
                    sf.setVisible(true);

                    s = server.accept();
                    InetAddress clientAddress = s.getInetAddress();
                    textList.setText("Incoming connection from: " + clientAddress.getHostName() + "[" + clientAddress.getHostAddress() + "]\n");

                    ServiceClass service = new ServiceClass(s,net);
                    Thread t = new Thread(service);
                    t.start();

                }catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException | IOException ex){
                    Logger.getLogger(ServerFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

when program launch it doesn't show me component into frame because it wait client to connect. When a client connect it shows correctly all components..how can i show all component without client connected?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what these lines do exactly, so that happens below might also apply to them.

```
SimpleDataSource.init("database.properties");
net = new Network();
```

The main problem is most likely that this line: `server = new ServerSocket(4444);` hangs everything until the client connects, which makes the main thread of your application continue execution and thus display everything.

To fix this, launch the server on a seperate Thread.

Something like so:

```
new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                server = new ServerSocket(4444);
            }
        }).start();
```

You will need to declare your server final, so that it can be accessed from within the `run` method.